# Getting an error when adding an email to the WooCommerce email list

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce

I want to add an email to the WooCommerce email list, But I get an error.

path : /wp-content/themes/hello-elementor-child/inc/classes/class-wsn-email.php

```
function add_woocommerce_emails( $emails ) {
    require_once  __DIR__ . '/inc/classes/class-wsn-email.php';
    $emails['wsn_email'] = new WSN_Email();
    return $emails;
} add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_classes', 'add_woocommerce_emails' );
```

path : /wp-content/themes/hello-elementor-child/templates/email/wsn-email-template.php

path : /wp-content/themes/hello-elementor-child/templates/email/plain/wsn-email-template.php

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->id             = 'instock_notifier_users_mailout';
    $this->title          = __( 'In-Stock Notifier', 'in-stock-notifier' );
    $this->description    = __( 'When a product is Out-of-Stock and when it comes In-Stock again, this email is sent to all users registered in the waiting list for that product.', 'in-stock-notifier' );
    $this->heading        = __( '{product_title} now back in stock at {blogname}', 'in-stock-notifier' );
    $this->subject        = __( 'A product you are waiting for is back in stock', 'in-stock-notifier' );
    $this->template_base  = require_once  __DIR__ . '/templates/email/';
    $this->template_html  = 'wsn-email-template.php';
    $this->template_plain = 'plain/wsn-email-template.php';
    $this->customer_email = true;
    add_action( 'send_wsn_email_mailout', array( $this, 'trigger' ), 10, 2 );
    parent::__construct();
}
```

> Warning:
> require_once(C:\xampp\htdocs\ii\wp-content\themes\hello-elementor-child\inc\classes/templates/email/):
> failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\ii\wp-content\themes\hello-elementor-child\inc\classes\class-wsn-email.php
> on line 51
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
> 'C:\xampp\htdocs\ii\wp-content\themes\hello-elementor-child\inc\classes/templates/email/'
> (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\ii\wp-content\themes\hello-elementor-child\inc\classes\class-wsn-email.php
> on line 51

where is the problem from?

Comment: The error message suggests that the file or directory you are trying to require does not exist. Make sure that the file or directory path specified in the `require_once` statement is correct.

In your code, the error is occurring on line 51 in the `class-wsn-email.php` file. Check that the path `'C:\xampp\htdocs\ii\wp-content\themes\hello-elementor-child\inc\classes/templates/email/'` is correct and that the file or directory exists.

If the file or directory does not exist, you will need to create it or update the path to the correct location.

Comment: Hi Bhautik, Thanks for the explanation, but I realized that it is because of the wrong path, But how to call the correct path, my files are in template child, As you can see, I specified the path of the files and called the files based on their path.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To fix the path using the child theme direct path, you can use the `get_stylesheet_directory()` function to get the path to the child theme directory. Here's the updated code:

```
function add_woocommerce_emails( $emails ) {
    require_once  get_stylesheet_directory() . '/inc/classes/class-wsn-email.php';
    $emails['wsn_email'] = new WSN_Email();
    return $emails;
} 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_classes', 'add_woocommerce_emails' );
```

Comment: I did this, I also did this : `$this->template_base = require_once get_stylesheet_directory() . '/templates/email/';`, I encountered a new error :

Comment: `Warning: require_once(C:\xampp\htdocs\ii\wp-content\themes\hello-elementor-child\templates\email): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\xampp\htdocs\ii\wp-content\themes\hello-elementor-child\inc\classes\class-wsn-email.php on line 51
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\ii/wp-content/themes/hello-elementor-child/templates/email/' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\ii\wp-content\themes\hello-elementor-child\inc\classes\class-wsn-email.php on line 51`

Comment: The error message suggests that there is a permission issue with opening the file in the given path. To fix this, you need to ensure that the file and directory have the correct permissions set.

Comment: In other plugins, I see that the email template folder has the same level of access, but there is no problem.

Comment: This is mostly likely ChatGPT (and the comments also look like ChatGPT)